# Rails: Sorting and Filting Data based on boolean attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a basic model of "Projects", which currently only has the attributes name:string, active:boolean. On the index view, I want to be able to have three links: Active Projects, Inactive Projects, and All Projects. These links will display the appropriate projects based on the status of the :active boolean value. Initially I set up the view by giving the links params like:

```
link_to "Active Projects", {:action => 'index', :active => true}
```

Then in the controller:

```
if params[:active] == "true"
  @projects = Project.find(:all, :conditions => {:active => true})
elsif params[:active] == "false"
  @projects = Project.find(:all, :conditions => {:active => false})
else
  @projects = Project.all
```

This seems a little cumbersome, especially since in future I want to have multiple filters, like due date, and client. What is a good way / gem to implement advanced sorting / filtering actions, without filling up the controller with a lot of code?

Comment: https://github.com/ernie/ransack is a great gem for filtering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could structure your params as a hash, and pass it to conditions:

```
# example:
params = {
  :filters => {
    :active => true,
    :name => 'Boby',
    # etc...
  }
}

filters = params[:filters]
@projects = Project.where(filters)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using `where` statements.. Also here is your code refactored :

```
@projects = Project.all
@projects = @projects.where(active: params[:active]) if params[:active].present?
```

Then you can keep stacking on items if additional params exist like so :

```
@projects = @projects.where(awesome_sauce: params[:awesome_sauce]) if params[:awesome_sauce].present?
```